# Customizing contact card layout in Outlook 2010

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin

I am trying to change what the Call button on the Contact Card does with VBA or an add-in. I want to start an application when the call button is clicked.

Anyone knows if that is possible?

Here is the screen shot of the Contact Card UI that I want to change.

http://support.microsoft.com/library/images/support/kbgraphics/Public/en-us/office/981022_ss01.png